# Display Page feed to webpage using XFBML

Tags: facebook-php-sdk, xfbml, facebook-page

I have a page I want the feed to work from the webpage
I can get it to work to my OWN feed but that is not the plan.

(https://www.facebook.com/pages/Inferno-Online-Stockholm/149232401793444) is where I want it to end up but getting to work from the webpage has lost me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fox

I have written a small Wall Feed Plugin you install with a simple iframe if you wish to check it out. 
https://apps.facebook.com/AnotherFeed/?pageid=149232401793444&since=30+days+ago&limit=8&type=feed&ref=get.code

This will work for any page or application, and can work for personal profiles when the post is public.

HOW?  I used php-sdk & graph api for this plugin.  This can be done with Javascript SDK.

- SEE: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sdks/
- SEE: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/
- SEE:
- SEE: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/